# sparkjava shutsdown randomly

Tags: embedded-jetty, spark-java

We have an REST application developed in sparkjava.

Suddenly at some point it shutting down without any cause in the log.

```
July 1, 2022 17:43:27.087 [Thread-27] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >>> Spark shutting down ...
July 1, 2022 17:43:27.098 [Thread-27] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@3e75ed9c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4567}
July 1, 2022 17:43:27.102 [Thread-27] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Stopped scavenging
July 1, 2022 17:43:27.102 [Thread-27] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - done
```

I don't see much CPU usage or memory usage. It almost like idle as it doesn't handle many requests at that time. Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Your log indicates that he program terminates normally. As in, there is no exception. Someone or something is probably sending it a kill signal. The question is of course who and why.

I am using Spark-java in production since many years and I have fortunately not seen this issue.

Not much of help, but maybe somthing :)

Comment: Something is calling `spark.Service.stop()` to (eventually) initiate the EmbeddedJettyServer `extinguish()` method.